# CompletableFuture to stop the main program

Tags: exception, completable-future

I would like to ask for help.

I have a process running a lib using CompletableFuture, I would like that when there is an exception in that lib, that CompletableFuture would throw an exception to stop the main program using this lib.

I'm using it this way:

completableFuture.exceptionally(....

but when you throw the exception the main program keeps running.

Answer (score 0):

`exceptionally` is like a `catch`, so you're actually doing the opposite of what you want by using it. Just drop the `exceptionally` and any exception thrown from within the future will be wrapped in a `CompletionException` and propagated to the main thread.

Comment: … and propagated to the main thread *if the main thread calls `join()` on the future*.